# c++ casting void* to int error

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

I'm rather new to C/C++ and I'm trying to use a C library that defines data structure PDS and provides methods to accessing the data.

Here's the function I'm using to access it:

```
pdsGetNext  (PDS *pds,char **pKey,PDStype *pT,size_t *pS,void **pD);
```

It basically returns the key of the element, type of the element, size of the element and the actual data of the element. The `void **pD` is describes like this in documentation: "Pointer to an address, which gets the actual element.".

I'm trying to cast the data to appropriate type as indicated by "PDStype". I'm having issues casting the data to integer, here's example code:

```
char *key = NULL;
PDS_TYPE type;
size_t size;
void *data = NULL;
float f;

pdsRewind(myPDS);

while (pdsGetNext(myPDS, &key, &type, &size, &data) == PDS_ERR_NONE) {
    switch (type) {
    case PDS_TYPE::PDS_I:
        // this is integer
        printf("INT: %d\n", *((int*)data));
        printf("INT PRINTED AS STRING: %s\n", (int*)data);
        printf("INT AS STRING: %s\n", (char*)data);
        break;
    case PDS_TYPE::PDS_PCH:
        //this is null terminated string
        printf("STRING: %s\n", (char*)data);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

The real value of the integer is 7, the output is as follows:

```
INT: 55
INT PRINTED AS STRING: 7
INT AS STRING: 7
```

to me it would seem that the first one, that I'd like to be "7", is what would print out if I had malloced the void pointer like `void *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(o))` and then tried to cast it as int like `*((int*)ptr)`

My question is: is there something I'm doing wrong here when casting it to int? as I understand it, the reason the data is returned as `void*` is to enable one to use casting in this fashion.

Comment: 55 is the code of '7' in ascii table. Maybe you wanna use atoi instead?

Comment: Why casting to `(char *)` if type it `void *` ?

Comment: I'm casting to (char *) because eventually I'm going to use the code in C++ CLI  to make a powershell module and use it with `System::Object::String`. Other types will ne used in a similar fashion.

Comment: what exactly is `C/C++`?

Comment: with C/C++ I meant that I don't have much experience with either C or C++, of any flavor.

Comment: A cast simply treat the bytes stored in memory as a new type. It doesn't make a number its representable string. Moreover it may get you into trouble if the pointer is not properly aligned.

Comment: `printf("INT PRINTED AS STRING: %s\n", (int*)data);` this invokes undefined behavior as you're using the wrong format, and `%s` expects a `char*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

55 is the ascii value of "7".
http://www.asciitable.com/

in C:

```
int a = atoi(data);
```

in C++11:

```
int myint1 = std::stoi(data);
```

since you re in C++ with data is a void* do a `reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);`
like that:

```
int myint1 = std::stoi(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data));
```

in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // to get a void* like you
    char *tmp = "7";
    void *data = (void*)tmp;

    // what is matter for you
    int a = atoi((char*)data);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

in C++11:

```
include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // to get a void* with "7" like you we could get the same with a std::string
    char *tmp = new char [1]();
    tmp[0] = '7';
    void * data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(tmp);

    // what is matter for you
    int a = std::atoi(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data));
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gives me basically the same result as earlier. Is there then no way to avoid using a method for converting char* to int? I was under the impression that the use of `void*` is for the purpose of providing a generic object which can be cast to a type.

Comment: If you only do the reinterpret_cast you will get the same result. Do int myint1 = std::stoi(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data));

Comment: the first case is '7' which is 53. in void* or char* the first case stay 53 for the character '7'. I complete my answer with test code which you can test. The firsts lines are to get a void* with the string "7" like you.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the explanation and examples, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "convert a char* to int" you are giving a "not well defined specification", since char* are meant to serve a completely different semantics respect to int.

When you "force" a cast, you are reinterpreting a same bit pattern under a different semantics. When you "convert" a value, you are changing the bit pattern into another retaining the semantics as possible.

Now, character literals (and string literals) are meant to be "readable text": `'7'` is not the same as `7`, and `7+2` is `9`, but `'7'+'2'` is `'e'`.

That is because + is an integer operation, and '7' is 53, '2' is 48 and 101 is 'e'.

Now, you have a piece of memory in which you placed the value '7' (that is the same bit pattern corresponding to the integer 53: the memory itself is agnostic to type semantics: it just contain 00110101) whose address is known as a `void*`.

Now, because of how `printf` works, %d requires int, and use numeric semantics, while %s requires char* and uses textual semantics.

Everything you place as a second argument will be read according to those specifications.

In your first case, you take the `void*`, use it as it is an `int*` that you deference (via unwary `*`) getting an int value corresponding to 00110101 that is 53, and give this to printf that treat it as a number, and convert it into the displayed text ("53").

In your third case, you treat the `void*` as a `char*` and give it to printf that reads it (because of the %s) as a "sequence of chars", thus printing "7".

In you second case, you take an int* and give it to printf where it expects a char* (because of the %s, and it treat it as such), thus still giving you "7".

If you want to convert the value `"7"` (a text) into the number `7` (an integer), you have to use a function like `atoi` and print the returned value (now an integer) with "%d".  Using %s will crasch, since `7` viewed as char* is almost certainly address outside your program memory space

Comment: I don't really want to convert `char*` to `int`. I was actually expecting the function `pdsGetNext` to return void pointer that points to an int, but I guess this is not the case.